# Calculate a value raised to a power with loops

Tags: python

In class we are making a program using loops to raise a number to a power with loops. I have got to this part but I am lost. Looking for any help.

```
base=int(raw_input("What number do you want to be the base"))
exp=int(raw_input("What do you want to be the power"))

def power(base, exp):
    res=1
    for _ in range(exp):
        number=res*base
    return number
    print number
```

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the value of number in each loop, so that the end result is it never changes. Instead, do

```
base=int(raw_input("What number do you want to be the base"))
exp=int(raw_input("What do you want to be the power"))

def power(base, exp):
    res=1
    for _ in range(exp):
        res = res*base
    print res
    return res

print power(base, exp)
```

Note that I've put the `print` statement before the return statement; otherwise it wouldn't have been executed. And finally, there is an extra print statement at the end to call the function. In fact, with this print statement, you don't even need the print in the `power()` method any longer, so you could as well remove it.

In case you want to do this without the for loop, you can simplify this using

```
def power(base, exp):
    return base**exp
```

Answer (score 1):

- You never call the function `power` you defined. Try `print power(base, exp)` at the end.
- If you were to call it, it would loop some, then return `number`, which is `res * base`, which is `1 * base` (since you never change anything, and do the same calculation in the loop every time). Consider `res = res * base` (or equivalently, `res *= base`) and return `res`, not `number`
- You would also not print anything, since it is beyond the `return` statement.